# Discrete Fourier Transform Folding with Frequency over the Nyquist Frequency

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, fourier-transform

I am trying to figure out something about folding in the DFT. Let's suppose we do the DFT of a function with a specific sampling rate of $\delta t$. Now I know that folding will occur, in other words all components in the power spectrum for $\omega > \nu_N$ with $\nu_N = \pi/\delta t$ will be folded to be in the range $[-\nu_N, \nu_N]$. If I indicate the Discrete Fourier transform with $F(\nu)$,  then I can write that the DFT as
$$
F(\nu)+F(-\nu+2\nu_N)+F(-\nu-2\nu_N)
$$
for the frequency above $\nu_N$ and below $-\nu_N$. Now my question is what about frequencies above $3\nu_n$ for example? They are not zero so that would be folded too. Therefore I need theoretically to write down an infinite series of terms. Is that correct? I hope my question is clear enough...

In the picture I calculated the DFT of a Lorentian function.

[image]

The blue line is the exponential function (the FT of the Lorentian), the orange line is the folded one and the red one is the sum of the two.
I would say that one need an infinite sum of terms (although in this case two would probably be enough numerically to get a good approximation).

Am I right?

Thanks, Umberto

Answer (score 0):

I researched a bit and the answer lies in the Continuous-Time Aliasing theorem.

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Continuous_Time_Aliasing_Theorem.html

I would appreciate if anyone had any information on what book I can find a discussion of it. Thanks!